# How to follow these instructions? [SQL QUERY]

Tags: sql, oracle

We had requested to change column SPORTS_MANAGEMENT_INFO to accept null values:
[image: Table details]

This script was used:

```
ALTER TABLE ALB.BLA_WR_CAR_SPORTS_MGMT_DTLS ADD (
  CONSTRAINT BLA_WR_CAR_SPORTS_DTLS_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (WR_ID, CAR_NUMBER, SPORTS_MANAGEMENT_INFO)
  USING INDEX ALB.BLA_WR_CAR_SPORTS_DTLS_PK
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

But we got this error at line 1:

> ORA-01451: column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to NULL
> https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01451.php

I was instructed to do the following:
"craft a query a find out if there are any instances of rows that differ in no other column but that one [SPORTS_MANAGEMENT_INFO]. if there aren't, it's safe to limit the PK to the remaining columns"

I am struggling to understand the instructions. The "… no other column but that one" is throwing me off.

Comment: Is your DBMS Oracle or PostGRES?

Comment: `select wr_id, car_number, count(*) from alb.bla_wr_car_sports_mgmt_dtls group by wr_id, car_number having count(*) > 1;`

Comment: I re-tagged the question with `oracle` as the error message clearly indicates you are using Oracle, not Postgres

Comment: A primary key column can't be nullable.

Comment: "craft a query a find out if there are any instances of rows that differ in no other column but that one [SPORTS_MANAGEMENT_INFO]." In other words: Find out if there is more than 1 record whose values are all the same EXCEPT sports_Management_info.  Mike's query above looks like it should do it.  as all that really matters is the KEY isn't duplicated.